# Property trigger does not exist on type data:String Jquery in Angular ts file

Tags: angular, typescript

I installed jquery in angular app and placed the code inside the ngOnInit() and the below 2 lines are showing the respective errors.

```
  $(this.element).on('click', Selector.trigger, function (event) {
```

Property trigger does not exist on type data:String

```
 data[option]();
```

Cannot call an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type String has no compatable call signatures

Ts file

```
declare var $: any;
declare var jQuery:any;


ngOnInit(){
if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {
  throw new Error('AdminLTE requires jQuery')
  }

  /* BoxRefresh()
   * =========
   * Adds AJAX content control to a box.
   *
   * @Usage: $('#my-box').boxRefresh(options)
   *         or add [data-widget="box-refresh"] to the box element
   *         Pass any option as data-option="value"
   */
  +function ($) {
    'use strict';

    var DataKey = 'lte.boxrefresh';

    var Default = {
      source         : '',
      params         : {},
      trigger        : '.refresh-btn',
      content        : '.box-body',
      loadInContent  : true,
      responseType   : '',
      overlayTemplate: '<div class="overlay"><div class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></div></div>',
      onLoadStart    : function () {
      },
      onLoadDone     : function (response) {
        return response;
      }
    };

    var Selector = {
      data: '[data-widget="box-refresh"]'
    };

    // BoxRefresh Class Definition
    // =========================
    var BoxRefresh = function (element, options) {
      this.element  = element;
      this.options  = options;
      this.$overlay = $(options.overlay);

      if (options.source === '') {
        throw new Error('Source url was not defined. Please specify a url in your BoxRefresh source option.');
      }

      this._setUpListeners();
      this.load();
    };

    BoxRefresh.prototype.load = function () {
      this._addOverlay();
      this.options.onLoadStart.call($(this));

      $.get(this.options.source, this.options.params, function (response) {
        if (this.options.loadInContent) {
          $(this.options.content).html(response);
        }
        this.options.onLoadDone.call($(this), response);
        this._removeOverlay();
      }.bind(this), this.options.responseType !== '' && this.options.responseType);
    };

    // Private

    BoxRefresh.prototype._setUpListeners = function () {
      $(this.element).on('click', Selector.trigger, function (event) {
        if (event) event.preventDefault();
        this.load();
      }.bind(this));
    };

    BoxRefresh.prototype._addOverlay = function () {
      $(this.element).append(this.$overlay);
    };

    BoxRefresh.prototype._removeOverlay = function () {
      $(this.element).remove(this.$overlay);
    };

    // Plugin Definition
    // =================
    function Plugin(option) {
      return this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var data  = $this.data(DataKey);

        if (!data) {
          var options = $.extend({}, Default, $this.data(), typeof option == 'object' && option);
          $this.data(DataKey, (data = new BoxRefresh($this, options)));
        }

        if (typeof data == 'string') {
          if (typeof data[option] == 'undefined') {
            throw new Error('No method named ' + option);
          }
          data[option]();
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell me what you actually want to achieve in your code?

Comment: There is a breadcrum in the sidebar with doesn't expand and collapse in angular I think its due to that error https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/index.html